# LINQ Query getting timedOut

Tags: performance, linq, wcf, dynamics-crm, query-performance

I have getting following error message in my custom log file :

```
2018-03-07 15:40:51,897 ERROR - The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:01:59.9880000. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.
mscorlib
```

Server stack trace:

```
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
```

Exception rethrown at [0]:

```
 at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IOrganizationService.Execute(OrganizationRequest request)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy.ExecuteCore(OrganizationRequest request)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy.Execute(OrganizationRequest request)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceContext.Execute(OrganizationRequest request)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.RetrieveEntityCollection(OrganizationRequest request, NavigationSource source)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.Execute(QueryExpression qe, Boolean throwIfSequenceIsEmpty, Boolean throwIfSequenceNotSingle, Projection projection, NavigationSource source, List`1 linkLookups, String& pagingCookie, Boolean& moreRecords)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.Execute[TElement](QueryExpression qe, Boolean throwIfSequenceIsEmpty, Boolean throwIfSequenceNotSingle, Projection projection, NavigationSource source, List`1 linkLookups)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.Execute[TElement](Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.GetEnumerator[TElement](Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.Query`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at ACE.Crm.Business.Logic.CustomerCommunicationsLogic.RetrieveCustomers() in C:\Dev\Crm\Active\Src\ACE.Crm.Business\Logic\CustomerCommunicationsLogic.cs:line 541
```

This is all happening due to one filter condition in LINQ :

```
var list = (
            from c in _crmRepository.Query<Contact>()
            join cn in _crmRepository.Query<Connection>() on c.ContactId equals cn.Record1Id.Id                
            join a in _crmRepository.Query<Account>() on cn.RecordId2.Id equals a.AccountId.Value
               where c.StateCode.Value == (int)ContactState.Active
               && cn.StateCode.Value == (int)ConnectionState.Active
               && c.BirthDate != null
               && a.ace_NetworkClient.GetValueOrDefault()
            select new ReturnedCustomerDataClass
            {
                AccountId = a.AccountId.GetValueOrDefault(),
                ContactId = c.ContactId.GetValueOrDefault(),
                aceContactId = c.ace_ContactID,
                <<<<<<< Many Other Fields>>>>>>>>>>>
            }
```

In `Where` Clause you can see a filter  `a.ace_NetworkClient.GetValueOrDefault()`.
When I am removing this filter my query is not responding and being stuck. Can any one suggest me what is going wrong if I am removing filter `&& a.ace_NetworkClient.GetValueOrDefault()` {ace_NetworkClient is a boolean field}.

In my result I wanted both customer for whom `ace_NetworkClient` flag is true or false thats why I removed that existing condition, getting proper result for local Org. but failing in production org due to large data.

Thanks

Comment: can you attach sql profiler to capture the query and execute it to see if its taking lot of time ?

Comment: Yes, I did as you suggested, ran that SQL Query it didn't stuck but it took too long (2.5 mins) to get executed completely. Is there technique like paging to run this query efficiently.

Comment: i would suggest you to analyze query plan if its taking long time.

Comment: could  you please let me know the step to analyze query Plan.?

Comment: you have ssms tool ?

Comment: Yes I have this tool, but in SSMS we can work on SQL query, but I doubt, how will I apply the same performance improved query in LINQ form ?